# I need help to turn repetive tasks into recursive function Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have function called *animateLinesDrawing_v1* that does the animation of lines drawing. The function takes 2 arguments , an array of lines and an array of circles and makes the drawing using canvas fabricJS, however there is a section that keeps repeting with certain patern that i want to turn into a recursive function called *drawNextLine*

```js
function animateLinesDrawing_v1(lines, circles)
{
  //Let's say we have 4 lines that connect 3 circles
  lines[0].animate({
        x2: circles[1].left,
        y2: circles[1].top
    }, 
    {
        duration: 4000, //line_1 duration
        onChange: canvas.requestRenderAll.bind(canvas),
        onComplete: function()
        {
            lines[0].setCoords();
            lines[1].animate({
                x2: circles[2].left,
                y2: circles[2].top
            }, 
            {
                duration: 4000, //line_2 duration
                onChange: canvas.requestRenderAll.bind(canvas),
                onComplete: function()
                {
                    lines[1].setCoords();
                    lines[2].animate({
                        x2: circles[3].left,
                        y2: circles[3].top

                    }, 
                    {
                        duration: 4000, //line_3 duration
                        onChange: canvas.requestRenderAll.bind(canvas),
                        onComplete: function()
                        {
                            lines[2].setCoords();
                            lines[3].animate({
                                x2: circles[4].left,
                                y2: circles[4].top
                            },
                            {
                                duration: 4000, //line-4(last line) duration, 
                                onChange: canvas.requestRenderAll.bind(canvas),
                                onComplete: lines[3].setCoords.bind(lines[3])
                            });   
                            
                        }
                        

                    });
                }
                
            });
        }

    });

}

function animateLinesDrawing_v2(lines, circles)
{
  //Let's say we have 4 lines that connect 3 circles
  lines[0].animate({
        x2: circles[1].left,
        y2: circles[1].top
    }, 
    {
        duration: 4000, //line_1
        onChange: canvas.requestRenderAll.bind(canvas),
        onComplete: drawNextLine(lines, circles)
    });
}

let n = lines.length;
let m = 0;
function drawNextLine(lines, circles)
{
    
    if(m !== n)
    {
        lines[m].setCoords();
        lines[m + 1].animate({
            x2: circles[m + 2].left,
            y2: circles[m + 2].top
        },
        {
            duration: 400,
            onChange: canvas.requestRenderAll.bind(canvas),
            onComplete: drawNextLine(lines, circles)
        });
        m++;
    }
    else
    {
        lines[m - 1].setCoords.bind(lines[m - 1]);
    }
    
    
}
```

My problem is on the recursive function does not stop running so that i can use it into function animateLinesDrawing_v2.

Comment: a) you must pass a function as `onComplete`, but you are doing a function call - wrap it in a function expression. b)  you're changing `m` after that call, which causes the infinite loop c) instead of using a global variable `m`, better pass it as an argument.

Comment: I don't get your point c. Could u please elaborate a bit.  Appriciate mate!!

Comment: ... `function drawNextLine(lines, rows, m) {` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd wrap the task *draw one line* into a Promise:

```
 function drawLine(line, circle) {
   return new Promise(resolve => {
     line.animate({
       x2: circle.left,
       y2: circle.top
    },  {
      duration: 4000, //line_1 duration
      onChange: canvas.requestRenderAll.bind(canvas),
      onComplete: function() {
        line.setCoords();
        resolve();
      },
    });
  });
 }
```

Then you can write that easily as a loop:

```
  (async function() {
    for(let i = 0; i < lines.length && i < circles.length; i++) {
       await drawLine(lines[i], circles[i]);
    }
 })();
```

Comment: Trying to wrap my mind around this. How will this promise replace the recursion function ?

Comment: The `for` loop basically does that: When `drawLine` is done, the for loop continues with an iteration and calls `drawLine` again.

Comment: Should that be the singular `line.animate(...)` rather than the plural `lines.animate(...)`?

Comment: Yes!! Also the for loop should be  `for(let i = 0; i < lines.length, i < circles.length; i++)
    {
        
        await drawLine(lines[i], circles[i + 1]);
    }`

Comment: I am getting this error after last iteration **Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'animate' of undefined**

Comment: Whoops ... fixed the typos

Comment: Then `lines` contains an empty slot